# Moderncv Package Question

Tags: moderncv

Must all `cventry` content be on the first page? My pdf doesn't print if there is too much content under my second `cventry`. How do I fix/work around this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Sub-achievement (a);
\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
\begin{itemize}
\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
\end{itemize}
\item Sub-achievement (c);
\end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
```

Problem begins here:

```
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\begin{itemize}%
```

Clone of code for `cventry` above. Prevents building in pdf if there is too much content for this `cventry`. Does this mean all professional experience must be on page 1?

```
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Sub-achievement (a);
\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
\begin{itemize}
\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
\end{itemize}
\item Sub-achievement (c);
\end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}

\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that `cventry` typesets its content in a `tabular` which cannot be broken between pages. One option could be to take our of the `cventry` the `itemize` and set the margins of the list so it aligns nicely

Comment: Also, there seems to be a typo: you closed the problematic `cventry` twice, once on the line you start it, once after the `itemize`

Comment: "Take our of the `cventry` the `itemize.`" What do you mean?

Comment: @Bordaigorl The typo fixed the problem. The other information you gave was helpful too. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my comment I meant "take out", such as `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` instead of `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}}`. Your MWE contains an error though that makes it ambiguous whether you are using one or the other solution

Comment: @Bordaigorl It doesn't compile if I do ~\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}.

Comment: I did not mean to use empty parameters in `\cventry`. What I meant is, close the last param before the `itemize` and make the `itemize` a top-level element. Maybe I should write an answer

Comment: @Bordaigorl I understood the intent of your comment. I didn't leave empty parameters for `\cventry`. What I meant is, closing the last parameter before `itemize` to make it a top-level element prevents compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains a typo.

In the problematic `\cventry` you must choose whether you want to close the last parameter before or after the `itemize`; currently you have an unbalanced closed bracket.

Since `\cventry` typesets its contents in a tabular it does not allow pagebreaks in between lines of its parameters.

A workaround could be to pull the itemize out of the `\cvitem` and modify its margins so it fits with the indentation of the entry.
This works with `moderncv` 1.5.1 using `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Sub-achievement (a);
\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
\begin{itemize}
\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
\end{itemize}
\item Sub-achievement (c);
\end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\newlength{\longlistmargin}
\setlength{\longlistmargin}{\hintscolumnwidth}
\addtolength{\longlistmargin}{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\longlistmargin]
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Sub-achievement (a);
\item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
\begin{itemize}
\item Sub-sub-achievement i;
\item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
\item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
\end{itemize}
\item Sub-achievement (c);
\end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}

\end{document}
```